# What is the '\?' Escape Sequence in D?

Tags: escaping, d

What is the [`\?` string escape sequence](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/lex.html) in D?

Comment: Probably just for escaping the `?`

Comment: After inspecting dmd source I can confirm it just escapes "?". But the reason why one would want to do so escapes me.

Comment: @Michal: Lol, you're punny...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just to escape `?`, a literal question mark.

There really is no reason for it to be in D, but it existed in C and C++ in order to avoid the question mark being interpreted as a [Trigraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). D doesn't have Trigraphs, so its inclusion must simply be for some added backwards compatibility with C and C++.